# How to find unused extensions in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs

We want to cleanup our on prem AZDO instance from unused extensions before the move to SaaS AZDO.

AZDO does not not offer any way of searching the usage of extensions.
Going over the documentation it seems that same functionality that is available on web interface can be done with API.
None of these will provide necessary information needed to identify unused extensions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such built-in functionality to audit extensions usage in Azure DevOps.

And the extensions will not be migrated to DevOps services when do the migration. You have to install them manually on the target DevOps Services org (SaaS AZDO) after the migration.

We can see the installed extensions by this url : `https://{server}/{collection}/_settings/extensions?tab=installed`. Please see [manage extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/marketplace/install-extension?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) for details.

Auditing extension usage on the on-premises DevOps server before migration makes little sense. You just need to install the extensions when you need them after the migration.